# No DNS resolution and Internet access from Kubernetes POD on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, kubernetes

I’ve built a cluster (v1.15.4) on hyper-v with

```
- linux node (master)
- linux node (worker)
- windows node (worker)
- networking - flannel (host-gw)
- mac spoofing enabled for vms
```

deployed win-webserver.yaml to test if windows is working.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/user-guide-windows-containers/

```
kubectl get pods -o wide 
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE   NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
win-webserver-7779dc4df7-58qs2   1/1     Running   0          18m   10.42.2.41   node01   <none>           <none>
win-webserver-7779dc4df7-mb4sf   1/1     Running   0          18m   10.42.2.43   node01   <none>           <none>
win-webserver-7779dc4df7-w5kjt   1/1     Running   0          18m   10.42.2.44   node01   <none>           <none>
win-webserver-7779dc4df7-wm245   1/1     Running   0          18m   10.42.2.45   node01   <none>           <none>

kubectl get svc
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.43.0.1      <none>        443/TCP        122m
win-webserver   NodePort    10.43.91.255   <none>        80:30378/TCP   72m
```

Deployment ran fine however containers running on windows can’t resolve dns and access internet.

DNS request from windows pod

```
DNS request timed out. 
timeout was 2 seconds. 
Server:  UnKnown     
Address:  10.43.0.10 

DNS request timed out. 
timeout was 2 seconds. 
DNS request timed out.
```

Also can’t access pods from linux using service.

```
curl http://10.43.91.255 --connect-timeout 30
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds
```

Flannel logs

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system pod/kube-flannel-8dqcc -c kube-flannel
I1015 12:48:40.437400       1 main.go:527] Using interface with name eth0 and address 192.168.x.x
I1015 12:48:40.437491       1 main.go:544] Defaulting external address to interface address (192.168.x.x)
I1015 12:48:40.538336       1 kube.go:126] Waiting 10m0s for node controller to sync
I1015 12:48:40.538380       1 kube.go:309] Starting kube subnet manager
I1015 12:48:41.538500       1 kube.go:133] Node controller sync successful
I1015 12:48:41.538539       1 main.go:244] Created subnet manager: Kubernetes Subnet Manager - node02
I1015 12:48:41.538551       1 main.go:247] Installing signal handlers
I1015 12:48:41.538676       1 main.go:386] Found network config - Backend type: vxlan
I1015 12:48:41.538751       1 vxlan.go:120] VXLAN config: VNI=4096 Port=4789 GBP=false DirectRouting=false
W1015 12:48:41.539007       1 device.go:84] "flannel.4096" already exists with incompatable configuration: vtep (external) interface: 2 vs 3; recreating device
I1015 12:48:41.632647       1 main.go:317] Wrote subnet file to /run/flannel/subnet.env
I1015 12:48:41.632666       1 main.go:321] Running backend.
I1015 12:48:41.632675       1 main.go:339] Waiting for all goroutines to exit
I1015 12:48:41.632695       1 vxlan_network.go:60] watching for new subnet leases
E1015 13:01:19.765370       1 vxlan_network.go:101] error decoding subnet lease JSON: invalid MAC address
E1015 13:11:30.468144       1 vxlan_network.go:101] error decoding subnet lease JSON: invalid MAC address
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

**Update**

I managed to get my cluster working. Reason for the communication failure was that I had two networks connected to each of kubernetes machines.

```
linux master - internet facing eth0 (192.168.6.2) eth1 (192.168.3.12)
linux worker - internet facing eth0 (192.168.6.3) eth1 (192.168.3.13)
windows node - internet facing Ethernet_LB (192.168.6.4) Ethernet_FW (192.168.3.14)
```

Virtual Switch on windows was created on Ethernet_FW which had no internet connection. 
After running Wireshark and tdcdump I was able to find out that
 - pods on master send traffic to windows pods via eth0
 - pods on windows node send traffic to linux pods visa Ethernet_FW
 - pods from windows send traffic to the internet via Ethernet_FW
That caused communication failure between pods.
I was able to configure windows node to create Virtual Switch on Ethernet_LB which had internet access and this interface (Ethernet_LB) was accepting packets from master and linux worker.

For cluster creation I used this resource https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/user-guide-windows-nodes/
I had to put proper interface name into config file

```
"InterfaceName" : "Ethernet_LB"
```

Comment: Sounds like your SDN doesn't work on the Windows host. Any relevant logs? (check for a flannel Pod running on your Windows host).

Comment: Flannel pods run only on Linux machines. Can't find any errors in the logs.

Comment: Updated post with the logs from flannel pod.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes.
Currently, I have working cluster 1.19.7 with Windows and Linux nodes in it.
Windows Server 2019 with the latest updates. Updates matters in Windows. Sometimes Windows updates may break cluster networking. I've had that happen about three times during last year.

Comment: @dzup4uk Could you describe your actions taken in a form of an answer? Few details and explanations would be very helpful for the rest of the community.

Answer (score 0):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As already confirmed by @dzup4uk, Reason for the communication failure was that there was two networks connected to each of kubernetes machines.

```
linux master - internet facing eth0 (192.168.6.2) eth1 (192.168.3.12)
linux worker - internet facing eth0 (192.168.6.3) eth1 (192.168.3.13)
windows node - internet facing Ethernet_LB (192.168.6.4) Ethernet_FW (192.168.3.14)
```

Virtual Switch on windows was created on Ethernet_FW which had no internet connection.
After running Wireshark and tdcdump I was able to find out that

- pods on master send traffic to windows pods via eth0
- pods on windows node send traffic to linux pods visa Ethernet_FW
- pods from windows send traffic to the internet via Ethernet_FW
  That caused communication failure between pods.
  I was able to configure windows node to create Virtual Switch on Ethernet_LB which had internet access and this interface (Ethernet_LB) was accepting packets from master and linux worker.

It was required to put proper interface name into config file

```
"InterfaceName" : "Ethernet_LB"
```

The Kubernetes cluster v1.19.7 was build using Windows Server 2019 with the latest updates as WIndows worker nodes.

For cluster creation this resource was used:

- [Adding Windows nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/user-guide-windows-nodes/)

Other useful resources:

- [Windows Server release information](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/windows-server-release-info)
- [Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 update history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/windows-10-and-windows-server-2019-update-history-725fc2e1-4443-6831-a5ca-51ff5cbcb059)